# Control react-select menu scroll position on opening

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Is there a way to scroll the menu of a react-select without actually setting the component's value or default value?

I'm using a react-select as a search box. So after the user selects something I want to clear what's in the input box and restore a placeholder "Search...". The next time they do a search they will click the react-select. I want the react-select to return to what it was before the selection - input text restored, menu open and menu scrolled to former position. I'm able to restore what is in the input box, if anything, and open the menu but the menu's former scroll position is lost and the menu is scrolled to the top. I would like that scroll position to be restored.
https://codesandbox.io/s/stop-indoctrination-d8pis